# Java exec on Unix

Tags: java, unix, exec, runtime.exec

I have the Java code below running on Unix (both AIX and Linux), but it doesn't work. If I run this code the file q1.01 is not compressed, and I don't get any exceptions thrown (The file q1.01 exists, and I expect to find the file q1.01.Z after the command runs.) At the command prompt if I type "which compress" it reports back with "/usr/bin/compress". If I type the command "/usr/bin/compress q1.01" at the Unix prompt it works fine. Any ideas on what might be wrong?

```
String cmd = "/usr/bin/compress q1.01";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Comment: Does the file compress when you run the command through a shell and not Java?

Comment: Java might be looking for q1.01 in the program directory, have you tried providing a full file path to the file?  Also, see if you can find your compressed file somewhere else on your system.

Comment: Perhaps you could try reading the stdout/stderr streams from the Process object returned by exec(). That might give you a clue why it's not working.

Comment: I left off some of the code details to simplify my post. I actually use the InputStream of the Process object to look at the return value, and it comes back null. I've also tried putting the full path on the filename, without success. And yes, the command does work from the shell if I type it in there.

What's weird also is that I've tried the program on both Linux and AIX and it does the same thing on both machines.

Answer (score 2):

[Later edit: the problem was in the initial description; the OP was passing a wildcard and not q.01.  So my answer below is wrong, except for the part in **bold**.  I'm leaving it so the comments after it will make sense.]

It's trying to run `/usr/bin/compress` as the program name without arguments.

There are many forms of the Runtime.exec() method. You're using the [.exec(String)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) version, which just takes the executable.  Instead, you need to use the [.exec(String[])](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])) array version, which takes the executable in String[0] and the parameters in String[1..].

.exec() wants a String array for passing arguments.

Try

```
String[] cmd = new String[] { "/usr/bin/compress", "q1.01" };
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

**Note that .exec does not call the local command shell. That means we have to do, among other things, wildcard expansion and even some argument parsing *before* calling .exec(). This is why you can't just pass it your full command line.**

Comment: I don't interpret the Runtime#exec(String) method documentation like that: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File) indicates that the argument is broken up into tokens using the StringTokenizer class.

Comment: Verified. Runtime#exec(String) does indeed split its arguments. Try Runtime.getRuntime().exec("nslookup www.stackoverflow.com").

Comment: Ah! I had tried this form of the exec method, but I had used "*.01" as the argument, and since it doesn't go through the shell it wasn't expanded. Thanks!

Comment: Hey - I was 1/2 right. Do I get 50% credit? :)

There is one other way to diagnose problems like this. Create a shell script which just writes its arguments to a file, and run it.  Then look to see what was written.

Comment: It fixed one problem, but the code still doesn't work. At least now I have several other ideas to try.

Answer (score 1):

There were a couple of problems. One was that I had tried using wildcards, and since the shell isn't invoked they weren't being expanded. The other problem was that I had created very small test files like this: "echo 'abc' >q1.01". This file was so small that compress couldn't compress it any further and so left it alone. (Stupidly, I think when I typed in the command at the shell I used a different filename, which did compress.)

Thanks everyone for the answers. It did help!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use an absolute path to the file.  Capture the output though, to see what the problem is - see [this page](http://java.sun.com/developer/JDCTechTips/2003/tt0304.html) for info on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html) site may be able to provide some clues.

Answer (score 0):

If the process input stream is null, I suspect that Java wasn't even able to spawn the subprocess. What does Process#exitValue() return?

I'd recommend using `strace` to see what actually happens on the system-call level. The actual exec() arguments and return code would be especially interesting to see.

Comment: The process input stream is not null, it's the readLine from the stream that returns null. Apparently there is no output when it runs.

Comment: Many Unix programs display no output at all when they succeed.